# How to GetComponentsInChildren for dynamically determined type?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a generic type "Enemy" that is extended by many other classes. So I can do `System.Type t = objectInQuestion.GetType()` to determine what "type" a particular "Enemy" is. Once knowing the type, I want to search an area for more of that particular type.

So I want to do a `GetComponentsInChildren<t>()`. I can't simply throw the return value of `t` into the template brackets `<t>` though. How do I do it instead?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you using `System.Type` as a method?

Comment: My bad. Corrected.

Comment: afaik there's no way to achieve what you want if `objectInQuestion` type is not known at compile time. You should try a different approach!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless someone knows a way to grab the list directly with dynamic type as desired, I presume the best workaround would be as follows.

```
Enemy[] enemies = someObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Enemy>();
foreach (Enemy e in enemies)
{
    if e.GetType() == objectInQuestion.GetType()
    {
        DoAThing(e); // Or add e to a list or whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a switch

```
    switch(objectInQuestion.GetType()){

       case typeof(TheClassYouWant):
       {
          GetComponentsInChildren<TheClassYouWant>();
          break;
       }

       case typeof(ADifferentClass):
       {
          GetComponentsInChildren<ADifferentClass>();
          break;
       }

       case typeof(AnEvenDifferentClass):
       {
          GetComponentsInChildren<AnEvenDifferentClass>();
          break;
       }
    }
```

Please note that you MUST put the class inside a typeof() when making a new case.

Comment: Ick. That's something I'd have to maintain with every new enemy I create. Not a great approach for me.

Comment: You could create a base class for the entity like BaseEnemy and then use the switch like that. Instead of doing typeof(RedEnemyWithHat) just have RedEnemyWithHat extend BaseEnemy and do typeof(BaseEnemy)

Comment: Nah, I wouldn't do something that would require constant update. Imagine if I have like 50 Enemy types. A switch would be awful. I might also forget an enemy type and not realize it until things break.

Comment: Thats the point of the comment i just provided. If you have all of your enemies extend from a similar class, you would only have to have one case for all of those enemies extending that class.

Comment: Yeah, that's in the premise. They are all of Type Enemy with extension.

Comment: I think the switch is going to be your only option. just putting Enemy should work

Comment: I posted an answer that does not require a switch.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. This is bad approach in many ways

- GetComponent**s**inChildren will allocate/leak memory
- Nesting such code in ai update calls will make it slow and scale very poorly (will work good for few enemies in pool)
- Working around (sensible) limitations of AOT compilation WILL result in slower code and even more memory leaks

Comment: Please explain this memory leak thing. The call will not be made on a regular basis. It's conditional upon death of the enemy. How will GetComponentsInChildren cause a leak? I thought Unity handled trash collection on such things.

Comment: Yes, exactly, in C# these allocations are not fatal, however, not so harmless. I've seen many times framerate being drawn to a still by this alone. GC allocations can stack up reeeally fast and, generally, it is a good idea to avoid them where possible and where it makes sense.

In this case Im warning about GetComponentsInChildren alone since it produces allocation (array object). And I've seen people using it in Update method :)

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, out of principle I imagine "finding" things is not good to do regularly. So I'll do it on start usually and keep track of it or upon a specific one-time event. Sounds like we're on the same page then.

Comment: Oh, totally then! Sorry for bothering you :D

Comment: Few months ago I was given a repo to work on where somebody was using FindGameObjectsWithTag in Update all over the project... Memory of it gives me creeps to this day! :)

Comment: Haha, yeah, it's crazy what some people might do! Glad you recognize the error of the ways!